# How to limit my iterations in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have this piece of code which is looping through the `posts` object and populating the table.

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
        <td>{{post.id}}</td>
        <td>{{post.title}}</td>
        <td>{{post.body}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Currently I have around 50 `posts` coming from a third party API call in the `posts` object.

How can I limit the iterations to only 10 so that all the 50 posts don't show up and only 10 posts do? What is the most `vuejs` way of solving it?

**PS**: I have just started with `vuejs`!

Comment: Try `<tr v-for="post in posts.slice(0,10)" :key="post.id">`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj that would remove only 10 items from the array, he wants 10 items to be iterated in the array

Comment: @user7814783 No, as per my understanding `posts.slice(0,10)` will return a new array with elements from index 0 to 9 in `posts` array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=example

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj oh yes, sry got confused , forgot about the return value of splice(). Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @user7814783 np :)

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj i tried your solution and its works pretty well. Also it look clean. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can track the index of each element in the `v-for` directive, and then use a `v-if` to not render past a certain index:

```
<tr v-for="post, index in posts" :key="post.id" v-if="index < 10">
```

Comment: Yes i already tried this but it seems a little cluttered and hard to understand. The answer that @mohit suggested looks nice and simple. However i am just puzzled now as to which one would be more efficient.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I like it because it reads more like a for loop, but yeah Mohit's is a good answer too. I think any difference in efficiency would be trivial.

Comment: Thanks @thanksd for your solution. However i will go with Mohit's solution which not only works well but also looks clean. Thanks.